# 3dsMAX Wire Param. expression: How to specify moving in positive direction?

Tags: syntax, expression, 3dsmax, maxscript

I have a wire parameter expression that I am trying to make do one thing when the value is moving in the Negative X direction and another when moving in the Positive X. How do I specify this?

```
if <moving in positive direction> 

then  A

else  B
```

I assume it would be something like if the new difference from zero is greater or less than the current one. That would work, but only if you stay in either negative or positive x-space. I just do not know how to write this.

I apologize if this is simple math. I am a bit new to this.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a more advanced approach than wire parameters. Using a script controller is the easiest way. It has to save current position in a variable, let's say prevPos (and the same for frame number, if you want it to work correctly when scrubbing timeslider backwards) - which will be the last step, as you want to first subtract the prevPos from current pos and if the result is positive, do A, else do B.